# How can I parse minutes to seconds?

Tags: c#

I want to parse the following input "10:05" in format "minutes:seconds" in seconds. So 10:05 should be 10 * 60 = 600 + 5 = 605. How can I manage to do this with code ?

Comment: I experimented with the TimeSpan class, but I couldn't make it work like I wanted. Thanks, tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just split the string, parse the numbers, and do your calculation:

```
string s = "10:05";

var parts = s.Split(':');
int seconds = int.Parse(parts[0]) * 60 + int.Parse(parts[1]);

Console.WriteLine(seconds); // 605
```

You can also use [`TimeSpan.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9.aspx) in this case which is able to parse this format if you add a hour part in front of it. You can then use the [`TotalSeconds`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalminutes.aspx) property to get your desired result:

```
double seconds = TimeSpan.Parse("00:" + s).TotalSeconds;
Console.WriteLine(seconds); // 605
```

Comment: And validate that there are 2 parts.

Comment: Note that timespan would fail for anything over 23:59

Answer (score 2):

@poke is close, but you asked for seconds, thus:

```
string s= "10:05";
double seconds = TimeSpan.Parse("00:" + s).TotalSeconds;
```

Returns 605.

Comment: What about "75:05" as the question makes no mention of hour notation

Comment: Wow, seconds? How did I not notice? +1!

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. Here are just a couple. If you know that the format is always going to be `mm:ss` then you could use the `TimeSpan` class, the `ParseExact` method, and the `TotalSeconds` property.  Here's an example of how you could do it.

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.ParseExact(mytime, "mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
double seconds = ts.TotalSeconds;
```

If you have a bunch of different formats that can show up you can use the ParseExact and provide multiple time formats. Here's an example that takes a few formats.

```
//HH -> 24 hour format always with 2 digits ("08" = 8 hours)
// H -> 24 hour format with as few digits as possible ("8" = 8 hours)
//mm -> minutes always with 2 digits ("08" = 8 minutes)
// m -> minutes with as few digits as possible ("8" = 8 minutes)
//ss -> seconds always with 2 digits ("08" = 8 seconds)
// s -> seconds with as few digits as possible ("8" = 8 seconds)
string[] formats = new string["HH:mm:ss", "H:mm:ss", "mm:ss", "m:ss", "ss", "s"];
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.ParseExact(mytime, formats, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
double seconds = ts.TotalSeconds;
```

Here's a [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) to the MSDN documentation for the TimeSpan class.  Check out the [Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.TimeSpan_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) for the TimeSpan class. Here's a [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx) on formatting time strings.

The other way is to manually split the input string into the two parts and use the `Convert` class to convert each part into integers or doubles.

```
string[] timeparts = mytime.Split(':');
string minstr = timeparts[0];
string secstr = timeparts[1];
int mins = Convert.ToInt32(minstr);
int secs = Convert.ToInt32(secstr);
int seconds = mins * 60 + secs;
```

Here's the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert(v=vs.110).aspx) for the `Convert` class.